# check-new-release process eating up resources on Ubuntu server 13.04

Tags: process, cpu-load, scheduled

A small Ubuntu 13.04 virtual machine instance I run in a cloud environment regularly becomes slow/unresponsive because of a proces called check-new-release.  Is there any way to disable this process and maybe run it manually instead?

Comment: Same problem on an ordinary Ubuntu 13.10 install on a new machine. I already had Prompt=never set.

Answer (score 16):

Try doing

```
apt-get remove ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
```

The script that you're seeing running is `/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release`, and removing the above package will remove that script completely.

A description of this package is:

```
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core - manage release upgrades
```

Comment: note: uninstalling this package can prompt the removal of several other necessary packages.  You can also disable the script (by emptying / commenting out the contents), or, it might only be called by motd, in which case removing / commenting out 91-release-upgrade in /etc/update-motd.d could work.

Comment: FYI: On an old 14.04 machine: apt-get remove ubuntu-release-upgrader-core python3-update-manager
REMOVED: ubuntu-release-upgrader-core update-manager-core python3-distupgrade python3-update-manager

Answer (score 11):

In the file `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` change `Prompt=normal` to `Prompt=never`.

You can also do this through the GUI, but that may not be appropriate for a virtual server.

You can do a manual check for a new release with `do-release-upgrade`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to solve the problem; now I saw that process creep up again after I had changed the configuration and rebooted the machine.

Comment: hmm, I gave the answer a point up, but had to take it back.  I'll wait and see and then come back.  I'm in the same boat, no GUI because it's a virtual server on digital ocean.

Comment: Me too, all my servers just had their cpu pegged for ~60 seconds by this process at the same time.  Not cool!  Also on digitalocean

Comment: This change did not fix the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is a pain on low RAM servers and 'Prompt=never' did not work for me on Ubuntu 18.04 so what I did (exit code 1 means NO_RELEASE_AVAILABLE):

```
mv /usr/bin/do-release-upgrade /usr/bin/do-release-upgrade.bak;
echo -n 'import sys; sys.exit(1);' > /usr/bin/do-release-upgrade
chmod 755 /usr/bin/do-release-upgrade
# chattr +i  /usr/bin/do-release-upgrade
```