# How can I upgrade my OS from the terminal? Each time I try, I'm told everything is up to date

Tags: 14.04, command-line, 13.10, updates

So I've been checking around on how to update my Ubuntu OS from 13.10 to 14.04 LTS, and each thing I see says to use commands in the terminal.  Some of the commands I've tried are:

```
sudo apt-get install update manager-core
do-release-upgrade
```

and several others. Each time I try I am met with something that says everything is up to date, or in the case of do-release-upgrade I got:

```
Checking for new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

Am I missing something?  Is there a file I'm meant to download for this to work, or does it look through the internet for whatever it needs, in which case it is failing to find anything?

So is there any way I can upgrade through this method, as I can't download an .iso as my computer doesn't have a disk drive, nor can I go through a flash drive, as I don't have any that I can use right now?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/453883/upgrade-from-13-10-to-14-04-no-new-release-found

Comment: Are you running `do-release-upgrade` as root or not?

Comment: I don't know.  I'm I got 10.14 as my first Ubuntu OS, but never really learned how to do much with it.  How can I tell?

Comment: Are you using the command `sudo do-release-upgrade`? That makes you root. It stands for Super User Do, and the computer will run the command.

Comment: I didn't at first, but I have since done sudo do-release-upgrade and got the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this procedure:

First: You need to update the system.

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Reboot your system to finish installing updates, and to upgrade to new available version:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In the open file, delete the content and paste this:

```
deb http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
# deb-src http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
# deb-src http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
# deb-src http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
# deb-src http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed universe multiverse restricted main
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

Continue run in a terminal:

```
sudo -i
apt-get clean
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoremove
apt-get -f install
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get clean
reboot
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am down to the bottom part right now on apt-get dist-upgrade, and right now it is downloading a lot of files, which I've never seen so far as I've been trying to upgrade.  I'll post when everything is officially done.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below command

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

The problem may have been because you aren't root.

Comment: Nope, still says the exact same thing as before.

Comment: are you trying the above command with root ? Please invoking the same as a normal user.

Comment: I'm using sudo now, if that's what you mean.  Still getting the same result though.

Comment: @Enahs so it doesn't work with `sudo` or without?

Comment: No, it didn't, but thanks to Kyodake's advice, my laptop is finally updated to 14.04.